# Drag and Drop ListView into CardView list

Tags: android, android-listview, drag-and-drop, nested, android-cardview

I'm trying to implement a drag and drop ListView inside each child of a Gridlayout.
So my GridLayout is composed with CardView (and they can be dragged/dropped too). It have been implemented with this library : http://patrick-iv.github.io/2015/05/04/drag-n-drop/
And drag and drop ListView are implemented with this library : http://nhaarman.github.io/ListViewAnimations/

The problem is the items inside ListView can't be dragged and dropped, there is only a scroll movement of the GridLayout.
As in my Activity I have a ScrollView for the GridLayout, I think the ScrollView of the drag and drop ListView is not taken in account.

And when I have only one CardView (so the ScrollView is disabled), the drag and drop worked !

So I tried something hacky like below, but nothing changed.

```
((GripView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.grip_view)).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        mParentScrollView.setEnabled(false);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mParentScrollView.setEnabled(true);
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

There is the XML structure :

**fragment_manage_program.xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:columnCount="1" />

</ScrollView>
```

**fragment_manage_program_item.xml (created inside the GridLayout)**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/exercise_card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:contentPaddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:contentPaddingLeft="20dp"
    app:contentPaddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    app:contentPaddingTop="20dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/exercise_name"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left|center"
            android:text="Pushups"
            android:textColor="#f44336" />

        <com.nhaarman.listviewanimations.itemmanipulation.DynamicListView
            android:id="@+id/dynamic_list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**fragment_manage_program_set_item.xml (created inside the DynamicListView)**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables">

    <com.nhaarman.listviewanimations.itemmanipulation.dragdrop.GripView
        android:id="@+id/grip_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/set_summary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have resolved my problem with that solution which required API level 21 :

```
mDragNDropListView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
```

For API level 4 or higher you can use [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html)